# I need to capture click event on map underneath the polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map, in which I put circular polygon around the marker. When I click in the map, marker is moved onto that position. When I click in the circle, it doesn't move the marker, as I suppose Polygon captures the click.
Can I somehow prevent the Polygon from capturing the clicks?

[image: Marker screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the `clickable`-option of the polygon to `false`

Comment: Worked great for use with Fusion Table Layer: `layer.setOptions({ clickable: false });`